# Multi-Line Statements problems

Tags: python, comments

Iv'e read various guides on **Multi-Line Statements**  but cannot find a guide that has comments, variables, text and text that requires splitting over multiple lines.

I'm struggling to split the below code:

```
ex = 25
cmd = 'raspistill -o ' + filename + ' -t 1000 -ex ' + ex
```

onto a multi line with comments, like this:

```
cmd =   'raspistill -o ' + filename + \   # explain line 1 
        ' -t 1000' \                      # explain line 2
        '-ex ' + ex                       # explain line 3
```

Is this the best way to split code over multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parentheses instead of backslashes to do line continuations:

```
a = ( "aaa"   +     # foo
      "bbb"   +     # bar
      "ccc"         # baz
    )
```

Basically when you have an expression in any kind of brackets, python will not end statements at the end of line, but will first wait until it finds the corresponding closing bracket.

I find it more readable and idiomatic than the backslashes.

Comment: One also needs to be careful, if editing in a windows environment, not to leave spaces before and after code see comment from  Jacobo de Vera below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're using, but this statement is probably not being parsed the way you think:

```
cmd =   'raspistill -o ' + filename + \   # explain line 1 
        ' -t 1000' \                      # explain line 2
        '-ex ' + ex                       # explain line 3
```

In Python, you'd get the error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

The problem is that the line continuation character (backslash `\`) isn't escaping the newline, it's only escaping the space after it. That's because the newline doesn't follow the backslash. It doesn't come until much later, after your comment. So you still have 3 separate lines here.

Get rid of the extra comments and put them in the front, for example:

```
# explain lines 1, 2, and 3
#
cmd =   'raspistill -o ' + filename + \
        ' -t 1000' \
        '-ex ' + ex
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using python. I tried to get rid of the comments, and still no joy. I get SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.

Comment: @reggie My comment applies then. If you attempt what you're doing in Python, you get, *SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character* which is what I'm referring to. You can't have any characters after `\` other than newline.

Comment: Hi Lurker, that error was after i removed the comments.

Comment: You removed the comments but you also have to remove all spaces after `\\`

Comment: i had spaces after the /, removed them and it worked!